# Symfony / php : avoid query to give nested json objects from one to many relation

Tags: php, json, symfony, relationship, one-to-many

I have  entities; Command, User, GiftCheck, and GiftCheckType  :

**GiftCheck**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GiftCheckRepository")
     */
    class GiftCheck
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=255)
         *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, columnDefinition="ENUM('Cadeau', 'Anniversaire', ' Nôel', 'Saint Valentain ')")
         */
        private $theme;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="giftChecks")
         */
       private $User;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
        */
       private $uniqueSerialId;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Command", inversedBy="giftChecks")
        * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
        */
       private $command;
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\GiftCheckType", inversedBy="gift")
     */
    private $giftCheckType;
```

**User**

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("tel")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Command", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $commands;
     /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GiftCheck", mappedBy="User")
    */
    private $giftChecks;
```

**Command**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommandRepository")
 */
class Command
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="commands")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CommandLine", mappedBy="command")
     */
    private $commandLines;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $status;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GiftCheck", mappedBy="command")
     */
    private $giftChecks;
```

**GiftCheckType**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GiftCheckTypeRepository")
 */
class GiftCheckType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $designation;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GiftCheck", mappedBy="giftCheckType")
     */
    private $gift;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;
```

I found my self faced to a problem, When I try to fetch my command data I got a nested json object ( like children / parent / children structure of the same object ) which contain giftchecks array, every giftcheck contain user object which have the same giftchecks list, the two images bellow describe the status of this nested JSON in the browser console log when a fetch the result with angular :

[image]
[image]

is that problem about missing serialization on my entities or coming from other side ? are my entities relations correctly coded ?

Answer (score 0):

please change User entity as

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Command", mappedBy="user", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $commands;
     /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\GiftCheck", mappedBy="User", fetch="LAZY")
    */
    private $giftChecks;
```

you can change other entities too if you wish

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany

also see EXTRA_LAZY for performance
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html#extra-lazy-associations

Comment: thanks for your response,  that's not working :/ here is a video show the data structure returned by the server : https://streamable.com/y2np3